# array has an additional undefined element after sending request to websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

so, first of all, i aplogize for all the bad code or bad names you may find here, this is my very first javascript + node serious project

the issue is this, i have this array called `stats` from which i store data from a module

### this is mostly setup code

```
var data = require("./data");
var stats = data.stats;
```

this is what stats looks like:

```
var stats = [
    {
        name: "test",
        value: 0,
        id: "0ps",
        isPositive: true
    }
];
```

the issue comes from when i send a request to websocket to delete any of the stats (0ps in this case)

this is websocket in frontend

```
function load_socket() {
  socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:" + socketport, "main");

  socket.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
    console.log("connected");
  });

  socket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (msg.operation == "listChecks") {
      checks = msg.checks;
      table.innerHTML = "";
      loadCheckboxes()
    }
    if(msg.operation == "listStats"){
      stats = msg.stats;
      statTableP.innerHTML = "";
      statTableN .innerHTML = "";
      loadStats();
    }
  });
}
```

`socketport` is set to `4444` or env variable `PORT`

this is the websocket in backend

```
wsServer.on("request", function(request){
    var connection = request.accept("main", request.origin);
    connections.push(connection);
    listChecks(connection);
    listStats(connection);
    console.log("Client Connected");
    connection.on("message", function(message){
        if(message.type ==="utf8"){
            var msg = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            if(msg.operation="add_stat"){
                stats.push(msg.newstat)
                for(var i = 0; i<connections.length;i++){
                    listStats(connections[i]);
                }
            }
            if(msg.operation="delete_stat"){
                console.log(stats.length);//this outputs 2 somehow
                // as you can see this function does practically nothing
                // only re-lists stats, at the moment
                //const newStats = stats.filter(stat => stat.id != msg.id)
                //stats = newStats;
                for(var i = 0; i<connections.length;i++){
                    listStats(connections[i]);
                }
            }
            if(msg.operation="reload_stat"){
                for(var i = 0; i<connections.length;i++){
                    listStats(connections[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    connection.on("close",function(reasonCode, description){
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(connection),1);
    });
});
```

note: i removed some of the operations else the codeblock would get too long

and this is the `listStats` function in backend

```
function listStats(connection){
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({
        operation: "listStats",
        stats: stats
    }))
}
```

### the actual issue

ok so the issue comes to when i call the operation `delete_stat`
when i make the call like this (this is inside a cell, cell contains button and 2 inputs, the input i need to get has the class `sIn`, i use it to get the id)

```
//note this references the button inside the cell
deleteStat(this.parentNode.querySelector(".sIn").id)
```

and this is what `deleteStat` does

```
function deleteStat(id) {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    operation: "delete_stat",
    id: id
  }));
}
```

when i call this function, on the server the stats array go from this:

```
    [{
        name: "test",
        value: 0,
        id: "0ps",
        isPositive: true
    }]
```

to this somehow

```
    [{
        name: "test",
        value: 0,
        id: "0ps",
        isPositive: true
    },
    undefined
]
```

that undefined there increases the length of the `stats` array by 1 which complitely breaks any loop
i could just filter out `undefined` from the array, but it's not really what i want to do, i want to know why does it appear and how to prevent it in the future

### last note

i'm complitely new to both js and node, i don't want to sound rude but please make your solution as simple to understand as possible, imagine you are writing to the most oblivious child ever

Comment: Should that not be `msg.operation==="delete_stat"` instead of only `=`   as well as `msg.operation==="reload_stat"`  ?

Comment: humm that's true, i made an oversight there, let me try it

Comment: This `if(msg.operation="add_stat"){` will always push something on the stack.
Change to `===`

Comment: @Heinz could you post that as a solution please, that solved my issue, i can't believe i've made a thread for such a simple thing, i will be more careful with if statements from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if(msg.operation="add_stat"){` will always push something on the stack.

Change to `if(msg.operation==="add_stat"){`